# TeXnicCenter with MikTeX fails to render many symbols, such as \nsubseteq

Tags: symbols, miktex

I am new to LaTeX (sort of) and my fresh installation of TeXnicCenter with MikTeX doesn't recognize many symbols. For example: `\nsubseteq`, `\subseteqq` and `\nsubseteqq` (and the superset counterparts).

I've tried exporting both to PDF and DVI.

Comment: Are you loading the `amssymb` package? Add `\usepackage{amssymb}` to the preamble and see if the problem persists.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Load the package `amssymb` (as Gonzalo suggested) or `mathabx`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathabx}
\begin{document}
\[
  \nsubseteq \nsubseteqq \subseteqq
\]
\end{document}
```

[image: subset symbols]

For other symbols, load the package which provides it. You can find it in [The Comprehensive LaTeX Symbol List](http://mirror.ctan.org/info/symbols/comprehensive/symbols-a4.pdf).

Comment: Hurrah! Didn't see any of these mentioned anywhere, assumes these we on by default. I think `amssymb` is nicer.